# Getting error while trying to download a file from a SharePoint page

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I am making a script task in SSIS to connect to a Sharepoint webpage and download a file from there. The script is in C#, and it's throwing an execption.

When I execute it, I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What does it mean?

```
string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();
object obj = Dts.Connections["HTTP Connection Manager 1"].AcquireConnection(null);
HttpClientConnection HTTPConnection = new HttpClientConnection(obj);
HTTPConnection.DownloadFile(FilePath, true);


Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: Do you have access to that particular location? Does the said file exist at the location?

Comment: Check the following article http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/07/how-to-download-file-from-sharepoint-by.html

Comment: I think he is following the same article. Looks very familiar.

Comment: I am checking this exact article, I even posted a comment there asking this same question lol

Comment: Answering your question, rvphx, I do have acces to this location. And the file do exist. I can access it by accessing the URL.